# why google stopped indexing my website and how to fix it

Tags: noindex

my website is www.examplaza.com

for over weeks or months now google have not visited my sitemap and if i fetch my page as google it will not show in google search even if i do site search in google.

please can someone help me with the solution.

am becoming bored of this. please solution and reason for that.

please help me out if you know the solution and thank you in advance.

Comment: But, [your site is indexed](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Aexamplaza.com)?

Comment: yes but suddenly stopped.

for weeks now google has not visited my sitemap